# Vue - Modules of store not accessible in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuex

My **src/store/modules/authToken.js** file is like this:

```
const authToken = {
    state: { 
        token: localStorage.getItem('user-token') || '',
        status: '',
    },
    mutations: {
      authSuccess(state, token) {
          console.log('hellllo')
          state.token = token
          state.status = 'success'
      },

      authFail(state) {
          state.status = 'error'
      }
    },

    getters: {
      isAuthenticated: state => {
          return !!state.token
      },
      authStatus: state => {
          return state.status
      }
    }
}
```

My src/store/store.js file is like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import authToken from './modules/authtoken'

Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.config.devtools = true
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        authToken
    }
})
```

In my main.js file, I am using the store as below:

```
import { store } from './store/store'
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  store,
  router,
}).$mount('#app')
```

Now, when I try to access the autoken module in a component file, I am unable to access it. I'm doing this.$store.state.authToken.getters.isAuthenticated

but I'm getting the following error when I try to use it.

> Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'isAuthenticated' of undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you forgot to export your object in your file `src/store/modules/authToken.js`. Since nothing is exported, the `authToken` variable you feed the store will be `undefined`.

Just add this at the end of your file :

```
export default authToken;
```

Comment: Great! This seems to give me access to my authToken state. Thank you! However, I can't seem to use the getters still. I'm getting the same error when I use  this.$store.state.authToken.getters.isAuthenticated but if I use his.$store.state.authToken.token, I'm able to access my token value. Why is that?

Comment: What happens when you try to use `this.$store.state.authToken.getters.isAuthenticated` ? Also, I suggest you use the map helpers (https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper). It might help you have a cleaner code.

Comment: Okay figured it out, I am apparently able to acces my authtoken getters by using this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated

Comment: Ah, that might be because you did not set `namespaced: true` in the store options. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem, so others users/readers can see the fix more easily.